# Youtube API to AlamoFire in Swift

Tags: api, swift, youtube, alamofire

I have a problem with my Swift code, that includes the framework Alamofire and SwiftyJson.

And I am trying to GET some data from the YouTube API trough this https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=kortsagt&max-re%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsults=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published

And the code works fine until it gets to the line with

```
if let data = jsonObj.arrayValue as [JSON]?{}
```

And just dies there.

Here is my example code:

```
func loadNewVideo(){
    if(loadingStatus == false){
        loadingStatus == true
        dataVideo.removeAll()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=kortsagt&max-re%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsults=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published").responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            //println(json)
            if json != nil {
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                println(jsonObj)
                if let data = jsonObj.arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                    println(data)
                    dataVideo = data
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
                else {
                    println("loading error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        println("Loader JSON")
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The works better as a comment but I do not have the reputation. At the end of the first answer noon stated that "You need to figure out how to turn the items into video data".  I was just hoping to add on to that.  Youtube will give you a video id.  You can play the video pretty easily using a 3rd party library such as [this library](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/), or [this library](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit), there are others and they are fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Up one for your rep and great resources in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You're making the call to Alamofire properly, but you are not parsing the data coming back from the server correctly. First off, I'd recommend you read through the SwiftyJSON [README](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). That should give you a good understanding of how to use SwiftyJSON at a high level. Then try working with the modifications below.

```
func loadNewVideo(){
    if (loadingStatus == false) {
        loadingStatus == true
        dataVideo.removeAll()

        let URLString = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=kortsagt&max-re%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsults=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published"

        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString)
        request.responseJSON { request, response, jsonData, error in
            if let json = json {
                let json = JSON(jsonData)
                if let items = json["data"]["items"].array {
                    println(items)

                    for item in items {
                        println(item)
                    }

                    // You need to parse the items into the video data
                    dataVideo = data
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("loading error")
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Loader JSON")
    }
}
```

It is not complete. You need to figure out how to turn the items into video data. I'll leave that portion to you.

Comment: Hey @Joachimdj, did this end up solving your problem? If yes, could you upvote and mark as the answer?

Comment: Awesome! Then you should mark it as the correct answer and upvote.